# MongoDB if statement in a parameter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, if-statement

I am trying to not make my code redundant and I would like to know, if in a .updateOne method, when Im passing data to change, if its possible to implement if statement to choose from the data. Here is a situation.

I have my db model:

```
const depositarySchema = new Schema({
    euid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    euid2: {
        type: String
    },
    count: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    euroPallets: {
        type: Number,
    },
    biggerPallets: {
        type: Number,
    },
    otherPallets: {
        type: Number,
    },
    depositary: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    }

});
```

Then I have a variable: var = 1 for euroPallets, 2 for biggerPallets and 3 for otherPallets. I would like to implement something like this:

```
Depositary.updateOne(
  {
   euid: euid,
  },
  { 
   count: dep.count - palletCounter,
   if(var === 1){
    euroPallets: count}
   elseif(var===2){
    biggerPallets: count}
   else{
    otherPallets: count}
```

},

where count is just a number. I hope its understandable what im trying to achieve, sorry for a wrong syntax.

Comment: It would be easier to handle the object if you first create it as a variable that you pass into `updateOne()`.

Comment: I thought about it, you mean that variable would be var = "euroPallets" for example and then use it in updateOne() like this?

Comment: { 
   count: dep.count - palletCounter,
   var: count,
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one:

```
let upd = { 
   euid: euid,
   count: dep.count - palletCounter
};

if (var === 1) {
   upd['euroPallets'] = count;
}
else if (var === 2) {
   upd['biggerPallets'] = count;
}
else {
   upd['otherPallets'] = count;
}

Depositary.updateOne(upd)
```

EDIT:

For .updateOne() method to actually work like I want to, you need to separate the euid parameter. The correct solution is this:

```
let upd = { 
       count: dep.count - palletCounter
    };

    if (var === 1) {
       upd['euroPallets'] = count;
    }
    else if (var === 2) {
       upd['biggerPallets'] = count;
    }
    else {
       upd['otherPallets'] = count;
    }


 Depositary.updateOne(
  {
   euid: euid,
  },
upd,
)
```

Comment: Great idea, didnt think of that. It has a little mistake I will edit it and accept the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Wernfried Domscheit beat me to it, but I will post my answer anyways.

```js
const palletTypes = ['otherPallets', 'euroPallets', 'biggerPallets'];
var count = ep.count - palletCounter;
var palletType = palletTypes[count] || palletTypes[0];

var pallets = {'count': count};
pallets[palletType] = count;

Depositary.updateOne(
    {euid: euid},
    pallets
)
```

I would honestly just make a helper method so you can just send in parameters and it will turn everything to the correct objects.

```
updatePallets(euid, ep.count, palletCounter)
```